# Are these guys supposed to be parodies?

Tags: area-d

In chapter 56 of Area D, these guys showed up. I'm not sure if they are supposed to be parodies of another manga or if they are parodies of people in real life?[image]

Comment: i know that scar from somewhere... darn i can't grasp it